# How to output a value (cost) based on a user selecting a range of dates in a form

Tags: php, mysql, date, calendar

I'm building a villa booking system for a single property so that users can book directly on the website. I'm struggling to find a way to calculate the total cost of the villa stay so that I can push it to my payment system (Stripe).

I want to create a form accepting two date inputs (arrival date & departure date), with two sets of potential day rates somehow assigned to dates in the calendar (for high and low seasons). This will allow the user to view the total cost once both arrival and departure dates have been selected.If the user proceeds, that value will then be pushed via POST to the forms action page where the payment will be made using the total cost value.

The issue I'm having is how do I assign costs to a form calendar? Would creating a MySQL db with certain values assigned to date ranges be the best way to go about this? How would I use the form date inputs to pull that information from the DB?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you post something that you tried and it may have failed you? That way it would have at least shown some effort on your part.

Comment: You need to assign a set of JavaScript variables that dictate the high/low season costs. Then use a change event to take the calendar inputs and find which costs apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines (not elegant, but a starter for 10):

```
var highSeasonDateRange = "xx/xx/xxxx - xx/xx/xxxx"; //use this format
var lowSeasonDateRange = "xx/xx/xxxx - xx/xx/xxxx"; //use this format
var highSeasonCost = "xxxxx";
var lowSeasonCost = "xxxxx";

$(function(){       
   $('input.calendarDateSelect').on("change", function(){
       var val = $(this).val();
       checkSeasonRate(val, $(this).attr("type") == "date");
   });
});

function checkSeasonRate(date, ISO8601){
    var highSeasonDateArray = highSeasonDateRange.split(" - ");
    var lowSeasonDateArray = lowSeasonDateRange.split(" - ");
    if(dateRangeCheck(highSeasonDateArray[0], highSeasonDateArray[1], date, ISO8601) === true){
        return highSeasonCost;
    }else if(dateRangeCheck(lowSeasonDateArray[0], lowSeasonDateArray[1], date, ISO8601) === true){
        return lowSeasonCost;
    }else{
        return "error"; //Error handler
    }
}

function dateRangeCheck(from, to, check, ISO8601) {
    var fDate,lDate,cDate;

    var fromDateArray = from.split("/");
    var toDateArray = to.split("/");
    var checkDateArray;

    if(ISO8601){
        checkDateArray = check.split("-");
        cDate = Date.UTC(checkDateArray[0], checkDateArray[1] - 1, checkDateArray[2]);
    }else{
        checkDateArray = check.split("/");
        cDate = Date.UTC(checkDateArray[2], checkDateArray[1] - 1, checkDateArray[0]);
    }

    fDate = Date.UTC(fromDateArray[2], fromDateArray[1] - 1, fromDateArray[0]);
    lDate = Date.UTC(toDateArray[2], toDateArray[1] - 1, toDateArray[0]);

    if((cDate <= lDate && cDate >= fDate)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Update:

```
$(function(){       
   $('input.calendarDateSelect').on("change", function(){
       var val = $(this).val();
       var cost = checkSeasonRate(val, $(this).attr("type") == "date");
       //Do something with cost
       alert(cost);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, David. For the dateRange variables, will it have to be MM/DD/YYYY as I'm pretty sure Date.parse will only accept that format?

Comment: @AlexGHooper I've updated my answer to allow for DD/MM/YYYY format, as you mentioned `Date.parse()` can have unexpected results

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added this to my page with two testing inputs with the first holding the class of  "calendarDateSelect". I can see the functions firing once the change event is triggered, however the highSeasonCost or lowSeasonCost aren't returning anything. ( see https://peydanegite.com/bookings/ for the test page ). I'm not sure whether I'm doing something wrong here...

Comment: That's because the functions are returning a value that the calling function is not doing anything with. Once this initial change call retrieves the cost, you need to manipulate this value to determine your outcome. I've updated my answer with an example @AlexGHooper

Comment: It also appears that you are using `<input type="date">` fields, these will format the `.val()` to `YYYY-MM-DD` format as a standard. So you will need to amend to take this into account.

Comment: Thanks David, what a simple mistake, apologies. I've added the alert to the calling function however it's giving me an error (peydanegite.com/bookings)

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much for updating the code, this works perfectly as it alerts the cost. My next step is to figure out how to calculate the difference between the two date input fields selected to give a "total price" cost of a stay in the villa. Would it be as simple as calculating the difference between dates and multiplying the `highSeasonCost` or `lowSeasonCost` by that value?

Comment: Yes, it should be. @AlexGHooper